# Opening shapefile and Tiff layer Coordinates do not match up

Tags: qgis, coordinates, geotiff-tiff

I am new to using QGIS and am having a major problem. I have the UK Ordnance Survey (OS) 1:25000 raster layer in Tiff format open. When I open a shapefile or mapinfo vector layer on top of it the coordinates don't match up. The new layer opens way off from the raster image even though the CRS is the same. Can anyone help?

The tiff layer OS map has been stitched as it came in separate tiles from OS. Could the stitching be throwing out the coordinates?

Comment: tiff needs the pixel number changed to represent scale in the tfw file example for jpeg is falknermap.jgw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: Does the tiff really need the pixel number manually changing in the world file? Seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Please post the extents of both files. More than likely, they're using different coordinate systems.

Comment: My IT knowledge means I'm not too sure what you mean by extent but I assume you mean:
1 25000 OS Map.tif|
projects edit.sqlite